# JSON file in "src/assets" folder not found

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do dynamic app configuration following this article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/. Browser returns 404 not found on the json file, although it can be accessed directly.

I put the configuration in assets folder:

**src/assets/config/config.json**

```
{
    "api": {
        "baseUrl": "http://xx.com"
    }
}
```

I have a service that loads the config.json:

**src/app/services/app.config.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { IAppConfig } from '../models/appConfig'
import { environment } from 'environments/environment'

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
    static settings: IAppConfig = {} as IAppConfig

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    load() {
        const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.json`
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => { 
            this.http
                .get(jsonFile)
                .toPromise()
                .then((response: any) => {
                    console.log(response, response.json())
                    AppConfigService.settings = <IAppConfig>{
                        ...environment,
                        ...response,
                    }
                    resolve()
                })
                .catch((response: any) => {
                    console.log(response)
                    reject(
                        `Could not load app configuration file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(
                            response
                        )}`
                    )
                })
        })
    }
}
```

The service is utilized on APP_INITIALIZER:

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { AppConfigService } from './services/app.config.service'

...
providers: [
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'da' },
        AppConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializeApp,
            deps: [AppConfigService],
            multi: true,
        },
    ],

...
```

I serve the app with `ng serve`. I can access the it directly with `http://localhost:4200/assets/config/config.json`. But the browser console complains:

```
ERROR Could not load app configuration file 'assets/config/config.json': {"body":{"error":"Collection 'config' not found"},"url":"assets/config/config.json","headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:15724
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2302
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:404
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:261
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1245
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2317
proto.<computed> @ zone.js:1569
(anonymous) @ delay-response.js:16
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:147
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
(anonymous) @ backend.service.js:278
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
(anonymous) @ delay-response.js:8
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
(anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:11
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:74
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:68
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._next @ tap.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/take.js.TakeSubscriber._next @ take.js:40
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next @ filter.js:38
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/BehaviorSubject.js.BehaviorSubject._subscribe @ BehaviorSubject.js:22
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject._trySubscribe @ Subject.js:89
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._subscribe @ Observable.js:78
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:28
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:15
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/take.js.TakeOperator.call @ take.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call @ tap.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
(anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:11
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:74
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:68
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
(anonymous) @ scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:15
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:98
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:910
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.toPromise @ Observable.js:96
(anonymous) @ app.config.service.ts:17
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:910
push../src/app/services/app.config.service.ts.AppConfigService.load @ app.config.service.ts:14
(anonymous) @ app.module.ts:27
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationInitStatus.runInitializers @ core.js:16739
(anonymous) @ core.js:17774
_callAndReportToErrorHandler @ core.js:17867
(anonymous) @ core.js:17772
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.js:17299
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:17213
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory @ core.js:17763
(anonymous) @ core.js:17803
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
(anonymous) @ zone.js:889
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:601
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:584
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:413
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:258
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:879
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:1012
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:17803
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:83
0 @ main.ts:13
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:83
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
Show 60 more frames
```

Hints or help appreciated.

**-- UPDATE --**

I found my own solution for the problem which I posted below.

Comment: Why don't you simply [import it as any TS file](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-j1dm9u) ?

Comment: What is the result in `console.log(response.json())`?

Comment: Result of `console.log(response.json())` is `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: error_1.json is not a function
TypeError: error_1.json is not a function
 `
Result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(error))` is `{"body":{"error":"Collection 'config' not found"},"url":"assets/config/config.json","headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}`

Comment: @olefrank have you seen my comment ? Have you tried it ?

Comment: Check the network tab to see the exact request made to retrieve the config

Comment: @Maryannah yes I tried it and it worked. But I cannot require it that way, because the JSON file will be served externally in the future. Your suggestion led me to the solution which I posted below. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 load() {
        const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.json`
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => { 
            this.http
                .get(jsonFile)
                .toPromise()
                .then((response: any) => {
                   var responseData =  response.json() | response;
                    AppConfigService.settings = <IAppConfig> responseData;
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch((response: any) => {
                    console.log(response)
                    reject(
                        `Could not load app configuration file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(
                            response
                        )}`
                    )
                })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Not working: `app.config.service.ts:24 {"body":{"error":"Collection 'config' not found"},"url":"assets/config/config.json","headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}`

Answer (score 0):

**My own solution:**

The problem was rather trivial. I am using the angular In Memory API plugin to mock all api requests until the real API is ready. That means that all http requests are caught by the service and instead returning the mock data that I defined locally. So the error message `Collection 'config' not found` makes sense, as I have no collection of mock data called 'config'.

So the solution is to use the setting `passThruUnknownUrl` to the In Memory API:

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {
            passThruUnknownUrl: true,
        }),
    ...
```

Now the collections not defined locally is passed thru externally.